# Broadcasting data to users every fixed period of time Flask + SocketIO

Tags: python, socket.io

In simplest terms, I need to broadcast data to users every 0.25/0.5 seconds. How do I do this using SocketIO and Flask? It is also important that the transmission can be stopped.

Here is example what I would like to achieve:

```
@socketio.on('startPolling')
def start_polling_signals():
    global signal_list
    while True:
       emit(signal_list)
       time.sleep(0.5)

@socketio.on('stopPolling')
def stop_polling_signals():
    pass
```

Performance in the case of the application being developed is very important, so I would like the server to send data with a certain interval.